# Draw route from source to destination on MapField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

I know I can obtain the coordinates from Google Map services. But how can I get the coordinates for the source and destination to send it to Google Map services, and then draw the route, once I get all the coordinates?

Edited:

i have something like this :

```
                bmp = new Bitmap(getWidth(), getHeight());
                bmp.createAlpha(Bitmap.ALPHA_BITDEPTH_8BPP);
                Graphics g = Graphics.create(bmp);
                int x1 = -1, y1 = -1, x2 = -1, y2 = -1;
               XYPoint point0 = new XYPoint();
                convertWorldToField(mPoints[0], point0);
                x1=point0.x;
                y1=point0.y;
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillEllipse(x1, y1, x1, y1 + 1, x1 + 1, y1, 0, 360);

                for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.length; i++) {
                        XYPoint point = new XYPoint();
                        convertWorldToField(mPoints[i], point);
                        x2 = point.x;
                        y2 = point.y;
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                        g.fillEllipse(x1, y1, x1, y1 + 1, x1 + 1, y1, 0, 360);
                if(i == mPoints.length-1)
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
                            g.fillEllipse(x1, y1, x1, y1 + 1, x1 + 1, y1, 0, 360);
                        }
                        x1 = x2;
                        y1 = y2;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a geocoder to get the latitude and longitude of a location. Google has one, documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/.

So after you get directions between the two locations, you'll end up with an XML file that includes directions along with coordinates. Override the MapField's `paint()` method and use `convertWorldToField()` to get the locations to draw on the map. From there it's just simply drawing lines from one location to the next.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I tried to achieve something like that. Will look into the Geocoding part. But when  drawlines i try  to zoom in or zoom out the bitmap size doesnt  change.

Comment: I'm not sure what Bitmap you're speaking of.

Comment: When i a draw a line on the mapfield, i draw it as a bitmap

Comment: I would recommend using `Graphics.drawOutlinedPath()` to draw the path. If you are wanting to still use the Bitmap, you'll have to do the scaling manually -- the map zoom level has nothing to do with the Bitmap

Comment: please check my question, i have uodated my code, what do u recomend??

Comment: Don't know if maybe it got chopped off, but you need to set `x1 = x2;` and `y1 = y2;` after drawing the line so it can start at the end of the previous segment.

Comment: ya sorry, the code i pasted was somehow not copied fully. This is what i do. I call this function on click of button, or should  i call it in paint(). Do you have any example indicating scaling Bitmap manually in zoom level. I am not sure where exactly to call the respective methods. Another thing when you say scaling manually, do you mean redrawing the entire path everytime the zoom level is changed?.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps does the route calculation for you, no need to do it manually. Use this syntax:

```
            double xPos = GPSListener.handle().getLocation().getLatitude();
            double yPos = GPSListener.handle().getLocation().getLongitude();
            String sourceAddr = xPos + "," + yPos;
            int moduleHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");
            if (moduleHandle != 0) {
                String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?action=ROUT&start=" + sourceAddr + "&end=" + lat + "," + longi };
                ApplicationDescriptor ad = new ApplicationDescriptor(CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(moduleHandle)[0], args);
                ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad, true);
            }
```